# Fatal error: Call to undefined function iconv_get_encoding() PHP while working with Google App engine and ZendGdata

Tags: php, google-app-engine, zend-framework, command-line

When i run a simple google app engine php code for reading google sheet data

i am getting a error 
Fatal error: Call to undefined function iconv_get_encoding() in/path/Zend/Validate/Hostname.php on line 1181

but when i checked in my phpinfo(), the iconv is enabled.
If i need to install iconv? if yes can anyone provide the steps for doing so? I have OS yosemite and google app engine sdk

So where did i do wrong?

my php code

```
<?php
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/Zend/Gdata" . PATH_SEPARATOR . ".");
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_AuthSub');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_SpreadsheetFeed');



$service = Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;
$client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient('$user', '$pass', $service);
$spreadsheetService = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets($client);
$feed = $spreadsheetService->getSpreadsheetFeed();
?>
```

Comment: maybe something interesting in there? : http://php.net/manual/en/iconv.installation.php

Comment: where is this error happening, on the development server or in the production server?

Comment: The error occurs on the development server. But now, i am getting a error message "ERROR:root:php failure (255) with: stdout: stderr:

INFO     2014-12-23 09:47:03,443 module.py:718] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -" thats it i cant understant why!!!

Comment: What's the version of App Engine SDK you're using?

Comment: what's your dev platform?

Comment: Is this issue even still occurring?

Answer (score 1):

For future readers of this question, this issue would be dependent on the local PHP installation. If this error occurs you may need to add the following to your php.ini:

```
extension=iconv.so
```

The iconv extension is [automatically enabled by default in production App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/runtime#PHP_Enabled_extensions), so this should not happen for deployed apps.